# how to skip elements in a list while checking all other elements remain unmodified

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to learn how to skip elements in a list while comparing it to a clone list with a different element set at a specific index

for example:

```
List<String> a;
List<String> b = a.clone();
b.set(i, "word");
```

so basically if the element at i has changed in b, what I want to check is if I can skip checking the element at i to see if all other elements remain in the same index of list a, I have tried this:

```
public static boolean check(List<String> d, List<String> a,int i)
{
    boolean check = false;
    for (int r = 0; r < d.size(); r++)
    {
        if (r == i) continue;
        check = d.get(r).equals(a.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(check);
    return check;
}
```

but it returns false every time I test it

This is for learning purposes, if you feel I am not explaining myself properly, please leave a comment.

Comment: So, you want to check if all corresponding elements of both lists are equal, except for index `i`, is that right? If do, `a.get(i)` should be `a.get(r)`, and you should break out of the loop as soon as check becomes false, otherwise you're effectively only comparing the last element.

Comment: Aaaa so basically a.get(i) is the culpit. I checked and you are completely right, that was a bit silly of me - thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code to this that checks the number of elements matching in the two Lists. The number of matches (held by variable **ct**) should be equal to 1 less than the List's size, since 1 element in skipped. **true** or **false** is returned accordingly.

```
public static boolean check(List<String> d, List<String> a,int i) { 
    int ct=0; 
    for (int r = 0; r < d.size(); r++) { 
        if (r==i) 
        continue; 
        if((d.get(i)).equals(a.get(i)))
        ct++;
    }
    if(ct==d.size()-1)
    return true;
    return false;
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: It has already been solved, thanks non the less, still that is an overly complicated method, when I can just skip the element with the keyword continue, set the boolean var to true then var = var && this.equals(this) and return it, which seems simplier. Still a good answer non the less and I will try it